# I need my Screen to wait for a thread to end before being pushed

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I need my app to start a thread (after clicking on a button) that does something, get me some variables then push a screen that displays those variables. The problem is that I can't get my screen to wait for that thread. Every time I run the app, I have to refresh the new screen to see the variables values. How should I deal with that? I used the `invokeLater()` method but that doesn't seem to work!

Here is my first screen's code:

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.FieldChangeListener;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ButtonField;

public  class MyScreen extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener
{

    public MyScreen()
    {      
         super();

         setTitle("MyScreen!");
         ButtonField bf = new ButtonField("Start thread", ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK) ;
         this.add(bf);

         bf.setChangeListener(this); 
    }

    public void fieldChanged(Field Field, int context) {

       MyThreadClass myThread = new MyThreadClass();
       myThread.start();

       UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
              UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new NewScreen());
          }
       });
    }
}
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: inside the thread, when you get the values , then push the screen.

Comment: Sorry, what should I do inside the thread?

Comment: inside the thread - after getting the variable, you can call the push screen.

Comment: or write a function to push the screen. When you get the variables, call that function.

Comment: Of course, calling it INSIDE the thread! How didn't I think of that. -_-
Thank you, that worked just fine!! :)

Comment: Try `java.lang.Thread.join()`, check this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/thread_join.htm

Comment: @Rupak, that's really an overly complicated way to solve this problem.  Simply do what Signare suggested (although see my comment on his answer for the complete solution).

Comment: @Nate, I will prefer the solution which will allow me separation of the screen pushing code and other code (the Thread, other business logic, etc.). If using `Thread.join()` complicates the solution then I think registering an interface to MyThreadClass in @Signare's solution will generalize the solution. Thankyou.

Comment: @Rupak , I tried the `Thread.join()` method. That works too. And is not as complicated as @Nate says. I think that it's better than pushing my screen from inside the thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this -

```
MyThreadClass myThread = new MyThreadClass();
myThread.start();
```

and

```
class MyThreadClass implements Runnable {
      public void run() {
          // here - your code for getting variables.

          // After getting your variable , push the screen.
          UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                  UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new NewScreen());
              }
          });
      }
}
```

Comment: Actually, this only *half* solves the problem.  Calling `pushScreen()` from the background thread won't work.  You can't directly modify the UI from the background, so this will throw an `IllegalStateException`.  Just wrap the call to `pushScren()` inside your `run()` method with a call to `UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater()`.